# position of feed stream discharge in the fractionating column

Tags: chemical-engineering

[image: fractionationg column]

In the book 'Chemical Engineering' by Coulson and Richardson (Volume 2, 5th edition), in the section 'Fractionating Column')(page-560), it's said that,'The feed stream is introduced on
some intermediate tray where the liquid has approximately the same composition as the
feed.' This gives no definite position of the feed discharge.

Our professor explained that the feed is discharged somewhere below the sieve plate, which is a plate situated in the middle of the column.

My question is, is there a particular reason for the feed stream being discharged here?

Can the feed stream be discharged anywhere in the stripping section above the liquid?'

Comment: You would make more work for the column by putting it low.  Ask your professor.